# Writing a custom character on an lcd

Tags: lcd, display

I am using a 16*2 lcd display as a dashboard computer. 
I want it to display a logo at the very beginning of the code, but some letters occupy the space of 4 characters, and are using both lines of the display, and creating those letters character by character (some actually require 6 characters) is very difficult.
Is there anyway i can address the lcd as a big matrix ? 
there would be 16 lines ( the oringinal 2 lines * 8 lines of each character) and 80 columns (the original 16 columns * 5 columns each character has).
This would make it A LOT easier.

Comment: Model of the display and links to technical documentation?

Comment: The display:http://www.ebay.com/itm/1602-16x2-Character-LCD-Display-Module-HD44780-Controller-Blue-Arduino-/171983948287?hash=item280b0ac9ff:g:RsQAAOSwtnpXmusW

Data:
https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/LCD/HD44780.pdf

Comment: In the character generator RAM, the user can rewrite character patterns by a program.  Page 13 of the datasheet.

Comment: If I remember correctly, you can create up to 8 custom characters (custom bitmap). You can then use those characters anywhere on the display. There is no way to directly set pixels.

Answer (score 1):

The chip you are using (HD44780) only works with characters; you can't address single pixels. If you read the datasheet, the word "pixel" is absent.

Of course, you can add a wrapper that implement a `drawPixel(row,col)` function by defining custom characters and then sending it to the display.

The result will be unpleasent to the eye, because there is a gap between chars on screen, and another gap between rows.

[image]

A better alternative is an OLED display like this:

[image]

You can find the same display with I2C or SPI interfaces. Basic model is B&W, but you also have color and touch sensitive variants.

Answer (score 0):

> some letters occupy the space of 4 character

use CGRAM to define 4 characters and display them over two lines.